# The pypy python3 interpreter won't recognize a folder within the current directory

Tags: python, python-import, importerror, pypy

I have recently downloaded pypy via homebrew with
`brew install pypy`
in my home directory.
However, when I went into VScode and tried running my program with pypy:

pypy won't recognize a folder in my current directory.

Heres is the format:

```
Analyzer
- testSingularSTOCH.py
- src
   - WMA (inside contains get_WMA)
```

I'm running this command in the Analyzer directory:

```
pypy testSingularSTOCH.py
```

And I'm receiving an error of

```
  File "testSingularSTOCH.py", line 3, in <module>
    from src.WMA import get_WMA
ImportError: No module named src
```

How would I fix this error?

I tried changing src.WMA --> WMA however, it still gave the error.

I tried removing src.WMA, but the problem seems to occur with the srcLONGTERM directory too.

Solution: brew install pypy installs python 2 version, must install pypy via brew for python version 3

Comment: `brew install pypy` installs the Python *2* version.

Comment: It might also help to create an empty `__init__.py` file inside `src/`.

Comment: You need a file called `__init__.py` inside of `src`.  It can contain just a single `#`.